# Fazer a borda do input piscar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de sinalizar quando o `input` de um `form` estiver errado.

Estou usando jQuery. Na minha cabeça imaginei isso:

```
if ($("#campo1").val() < 0){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('#campo2').attr('style', 'border-color: red');
        sleep(1000);
        $('#campo2').attr('style', 'border-color: #cccccc');
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Mas não esta funcionando. Certamente na prática não deve ser assim.

Comment: Estiver errado? O que seria errado? Vazio? Tente ser mais especifico.

Comment: Certamente falta a largura da borda acho que o atributo é `border-weigth`.

Comment: @sant0will Essa é a condução `if ($("#campo1").val() < 0){ `

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Ele fica vermelho, mas não pisca, como a ideia original. Então quer dizer que meu código não é a forma correta de se fazer isso.

Comment: Ahhh entendi errado, não seria os 1 segundo?

Comment: talvez vc deva diminuir o tempo

Comment: Te interessa uma resposta só com CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `for` você não consegue fazer isso. Poderia usar uma função recursiva, desta forma:

```js
var temp1, temp2;
if ($("#campo1").val() < 0){
   let i = 0;
   function pisca(){
      $('#campo2').css('border-color', 'red');
      if(i < 10){
         temp1 = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#campo2').css('border-color', '#ccc');
            temp2 = setTimeout(pisca, 500);
            i++;
         }, 500);
      }
   }
   pisca();
}

$("#campo1").on("input", function(){

   if(this.value > -1){
      clearTimeout(temp1);
      clearTimeout(temp2);
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campo1" type="number" value="-1">
<input id="campo2" type="text">
```

Comment: Como fazer para parar o pisca quando a pessoa digitar um valor POSITIVO?

Comment: Resposta editada.

Comment: Parou não...rsrs

Comment: Veja agora rs...

Comment: Show, obrigado :)